# Fourier Series of a piecewise function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, bounds-of-integration

I have to find the Fourier series of the following function:

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      1 & \pi/2 < |x| < \pi \\
      0 & otherwise \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$
I don't understand how to find the bounds for the integration (to find $b_k$ and $a_k$).

Could somebody please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: They meant the Fourier series of the $2\pi$-periodic function $f(x+2\pi n) = 1$ if $|x|\in (\pi/2,\pi)$, $0$ otherwise. The Fourier coefficients are found as usual with $a_k = \int_{c}^{c+2\pi} f(x) \cos(kx)dx$

Comment: @reuns I'm afraid they don't, as this is this is another question in the book

Comment: I'm affraid you don't understand that Fourier series is for periodic functions, those being fully determined by their values on one period. What I wrote is what they meant. The biggest problem in your question is that you didn't give the period $T$, for each $T$ you'll have a different periodic function and Fourier series.

Comment: @reuns T is not given in the question, I copied everything that is given in the question

Comment: That's why I said $T$ is given somewhere else as $2\pi$. Once $T$ is given do you see that the question is unambiguous ? If so there is nothing else to say (except of course the main theorem, that the Fourier series converges to $f$ because it is piecewise $C^1$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $m\in \Bbb{Z}$

$\pi \geq|x| \geq \pi/2$ if and only if $x \in [-\pi,-\pi/2]\cup [\pi/2,\pi]$

Also note that $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$

Then $$\hat{f}(m)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-imx}dx+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}e^{-imx}dx$$

So from this you can find $a_m,b_m$

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: @Shaun i edited my answer

Comment: Note that the coefficines have bound of integration the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, and you functions vanishes somewhere so you have the answer above.